# What happens when flet is inside a recursive function?

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

I've been trying to implement an NFA, and the code at the bottom is to derive the epsilon closure of all the current states.
I'd like to implement it using in recursive style, because the epsilon closure is by definition recursive. In the current implementation, a helper function is defined inside the main function using `flet`, and it seems that every time of the recursion a helper function is independently defined. Is my understanding correct? If so, what is the tidiest way to implement this code without defining the same thing many times?

```
(defun eps-closure (states transition-rule)
  (flet ((trace-eps-onestep (states transition-rule)
           (remove-duplicates
            (flatten
             (append
              states
              (mapcar
               (lambda (state) (transition-state state :eps transition-rule))
               states))))))
    (let ((next (trace-eps-onestep states transition-rule)))
      (if (set-difference next states)
          (eps-closure next transition-rule)
          next))))
```

Comment: Just define it as an ordinary function once, instead of using `FLET`.

Comment: The function will be in the global scope by doing so. Can I avoid that? I found that defun inside flet seems to work as I want. Is this a common way of implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me that looks okay. It's a typical local lexical function.

> it seems that every time of the recursion a helper function is independently defined

This does not matter in compiled code and the function is not *redefined* anyway. There is no function object being created and there is no assignment to a symbol taking place. A compiler might even decide to inline it.

Interpreted code (by using an interpreter for s-expressions) might have some overhead executing the FLET statement on each iteration, but for compiled code this does not matter much, since the compilation is usually done once *ahead of time*.

To make code a bit more modular with functions there are ways:

- just like in your example, define a local function. I would even keep the parameters, even though they can be omitted when they are in lexical scope. Optionally declare to inline the local function. Keeping the parameters makes code refactoring simpler and serves documenting the arguments to the function by making them explicit.
- define it as a global function and feed all arguments to it in the call later. Often these functions are named as helper functions like `%trace-eps-onestep` (using `%` as a prefix for global functions who are not supposed to be called directly) or similar. Sometimes this is preferred, since it makes independently tracing the helper function easier. But some implementations can also trace local functions individually.

**global FLET: avoid**

Taking the FLET around the DEFUN is not great, since it makes the DEFUN form non *top-level* and prevents the *file compiler* from portably recognizing it as a global function definition during file compilation.

**Example using the SBCL compiler**

```
* (defun add42 (n)
    (flet ((do-it (n)
             (+ n 42)))
      (let ((x (do-it n)))
        (if (> x 100)
            :i-dont-do-it
            x))))

* (disassemble #'add42)
; disassembly for ADD42
; Size: 68 bytes. Origin: #x22661D81                          ; ADD42
; 81:       498B4510         MOV RAX, [R13+16]                ; thread.binding-stack-pointer
; 85:       488945F8         MOV [RBP-8], RAX
; 89:       488B55F0         MOV RDX, [RBP-16]
; 8D:       BF54000000       MOV EDI, 84
; 92:       FF1425C000B021   CALL QWORD PTR [#x21B000C0]      ; GENERIC-+
; 99:       488BC2           MOV RAX, RDX
; 9C:       488945E8         MOV [RBP-24], RAX
; A0:       BFC8000000       MOV EDI, 200
; A5:       FF1425E800B021   CALL QWORD PTR [#x21B000E8]      ; GENERIC->
; AC:       488B45E8         MOV RAX, [RBP-24]
; B0:       488BD0           MOV RDX, RAX
; B3:       41BB0FC04E20     MOV R11D, #x204EC00F             ; :I-DONT-DO-IT
; B9:       490F4FD3         CMOVNLE RDX, R11
; BD:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP
; C0:       F8               CLC
; C1:       5D               POP RBP
; C2:       C3               RET
; C3:       CC10             INT3 16                          ; Invalid argument count trap
NIL
```

As you can see from the generated x86-64 machine code, there are no *redefinitions* going on.

Comment: I thought that `defun` _always_ defines functions in the global scope, even when the `defun` form itself is not a top level form.

Comment: @exnihilo: it does, but the file compiler won't know `eps-closure` is a global function during compilation time.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly obvious way to do something like this is to define the tail-recursive loop inside any locally-defined functions that you want:

```
(defun eps-closure (initial-states transition-rule)
  (flet ((trace-eps-onestep (states)
           (remove-duplicates
            (flatten
             (append
              states
              (mapcar
               (lambda (state) (transition-state state :eps transition-rule))
               states))))))
    (labels ((eps-closure-loop (states)
               (let ((next (trace-eps-onestep states)))
                 (if (set-difference next states)
                     (eps-closure-loop states)
                   next))))
      (eps-closure-loop initial-states))))
```

Now it is completely clear that there is only one definition of `trace-eps-onestep`.  Note that I have also taken the opportunity to remove the second argument from all the calls as it is always the same object, and I've renamed arguments to make, I hope, more sense.

I like this kind of big-global-definition-with-a-bunch-of-local-functions-inside it trick, as it means that it is completely clear from reading the code that they are auxiliary functions only for use by the global function.

In this particular case, `trace-eps-onestep` is called from exactly one place, and really has no reason to exist at all.  A good compiler will probably optimize it completely away, but I think that the following code is clearer in any case:

```
(defun eps-closure (initial-states transition-rule)
  (labels ((eps-closure-loop (states)
             (let ((next (remove-duplicates
                          (flatten
                           (append
                            states
                            (mapcar
                             (lambda (state)
                               (transition-state state :eps transition-rule))
                             states))))))
               (if (set-difference next states)
                   (eps-closure-loop next)
                 next))))
    (eps-closure-loop initial-states)))
```

Finally this kind of tail-recursive-local-function is not very natural in CL (although I very often program like this!): something like the following is arguably clearer I think:

```
(defun eps-closure (initial-states transition-rule)
  (loop for states = initial-states then next
        for next = (remove-duplicates
                    (flatten
                     (append
                      states
                      (mapcar
                       (lambda (state)
                         (transition-state state :eps transition-rule))
                       states))))
        if (null (set-difference next states))
        return next))
```

I have not tested any of these functions (they all compile, but there are missing definitions).

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `FLET` around the `DEFUN`, so it won't be in the global scope.

```
(flet ((trace-eps-onestep (states transition-rule)
          (remove-duplicates
           (flatten
            (append
             states
             (mapcar
              (lambda (state) (transition-state state :eps transition-rule))
              states))))))
  (defun eps-closure (states transition-rule)
    (let ((next (trace-eps-onestep states transition-rule)))
      (if (set-difference next states)
          (eps-closure next transition-rule)
        next))))
```

Or you could define it locally as in your original code. There's no need to pass parameters to it, since the local function has access to all the local variables. In this case, it's reasonable to redefine it on every recursion, because the variables are different.

```
(defun eps-closure (states transition-rule)
  (flet ((trace-eps-onestep ()
           (remove-duplicates
            (flatten
             (append
              states
              (mapcar
               (lambda (state) (transition-state state :eps transition-rule))
               states))))))
    (let ((next (trace-eps-onestep)))
      (if (set-difference next states)
          (eps-closure next transition-rule)
          next))))
```

Comment: But why would anyone do this?

Comment: As he said in the comment, he doesn't want the helper function to be in the global scope.

Comment: Why not just leave it in local scope, that's what local functions are often used for... ?

Comment: Because then it redefines the function every time, which is unnecessary since it's the same function.

Comment: The function gets redefined every time? Why would a compiler do that?